# Function Satisfying Integral Relation

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm digging around for a function that satisfies the following integral relationship:

$$
\int_A [f(x)]^k dx = \frac{k-1}{k}
$$

Where $A$ is some subset of the domain of $f$.  I've messed around a bit but it seems to be difficult to find such a function.  Any thoughts on how to solve for it would be great.  Thanks!

Comment: Is $k$ fixed? What about $f(x) = 1$ and $A = (1,-1/k) \subset \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: No, it is not fixed, but thanks for pointing out the ambiguity.

Comment: This is a "moment problem" ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_problem ... Change variables to make it look like $\int_B y^k \;d\mu(y)=\frac{k-1}{k}$ where we need to find the measure $\mu$.  As Robert noted, it cannot be a nonnegative measure.  Can it be a signed measure?  Can it be a complex measure?  And if so, does the measure have a density so we can convert back to the $f(x)$ form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably you want this for all integers $k \ge 1$.
It won't work for a real-valued function.  Note that by the Cauchy-Schwarz
 inequality
$$ \left(\int_A |f(x)|^{a+b}\; dx\right)^2 \le \int_A |f(x)|^{2a}\; dx \ \int_A |f(x)|^{2b}\; dx  $$
Try this with $a=2$ and $b=4$, and we get
$$ \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^2 \le \frac{21}{32}$$
which is false.